# Unitarity implies branch cuts in $s > 4m^2$ in the $S$-matrix

Tags: hilbert-space, s-matrix-theory, unitarity

Why does unitarity imply a branch cut in the $S$-matrix after $s > 4m^2$ where $s$ is the Mandlestam variable and $m$ is the mass of the particle? Assume identical particle scattering.

Comment: this reads awfully like a homework question...

Comment: related/possible dup? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/289775/84967

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because particle pairs produce a continuous spectrum with energy $(2m)^2+K$, where $K\ge 0$ is the arbitrary relative relativistic kinetic energy.