# Contribution from one-particle states and multiparticle states to the two-point function in Källen-Lehmann representation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, renormalization, propagator

There are two points I'm confused about the Källén-Lehmann spectral representation as presented in Peskin & Schroeder. In that representation the two-point function is written as $$\langle \Omega|T\{\phi(x)\phi(y)\}|\Omega\rangle=\int_0^\infty \dfrac{dM^2}{2\pi}\rho(M^2)D_F(x-y;M^2)\tag{7.6}$$

where $\rho(M^2)$ is a positive spectral density function, $$\rho(M^2)=\sum_\lambda (2\pi)\delta(M^2-m_\lambda^2)|\langle \Omega|\phi(0)|\lambda_0\rangle|^2.\tag{7.7}$$

Now Peskin & Schroeder say that we can extract the one-particle states contribution and write $$\rho(M^2)=2\pi \delta(M^2-m^2)\cdot Z+(\text{nothing else until $M\gtrapprox (2m)^2$})\tag{7.8}$$

My confusion is on this (7.8). The first term I think I understand: the sum on (7.7) are over all momentum eigenstates $|\lambda_0\rangle$ which have zero-momentum $\mathbf{P}|\lambda_0\rangle=0$. The single-particle state with mass $m$ constraint $P^2|\lambda_0\rangle=m^2|\lambda_0\rangle$ can be solved by just one state. So the single-particle contribution to (7.7) is that of a single state $|\lambda_0^1\rangle$, say, and then $Z = |\langle \Omega|\phi(0)|\lambda_0^1\rangle|^2$.

On the other hand I can't understand the rest of (7.8).  Why there is "nothing else until $M\gtrapprox (2m)^2$" ? I guess I have the intuitive idea. After one-particle states we should have two-particle states and then if the momentum is zero the energy will be $2m$.

Still I can't understand *rigorously* why this should be the case. This argument that "after one-particle states we have two-particle states" is very clear in free theory where we have the Fock space picture, but it is unclear in the interacting theory for me.

Also Peskin & Schroeder talk about a branch cut in the Fourier transform of (7.6) as a function of $p^2$ beginning at $p^2=(2m)^2$ and I also don't see how it appears from (7.7).

So my questions are:

1. Is my understanding of the first term in (7.8) correct?
2. Where does the second term in (7.8) come from? Why there is "nothing else until $M\gtrapprox(2m)^2$"?
3. Why is there a branch cut in the Fourier transform of (7.6) as a function of $p^2$ beginning at $p^2=(2m)^2$?

Comment: Regarding question 2: The paragraph containing equation (7.8) starts with "The spectral density... for a *typical* theory is plotted in Fig 7.2" (emphasis added). I don't think they're claiming to have derived the $\gtrsim(2m)^2$ condition, they're just asserting that it's typical. Are you asking why they say it's typical?

Comment: I had seem it but at first I thought the comment was just about the figure and that somehow they were claiming (7.8) follows generically. If (7.8) does not follow generically it would be nice to understand why it is typical and when it would not be like that. Regarding the branch cut, on the other hand, I think they are saying that it always appears, right?

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/289775/84967